# Cyclic groups: What is the difference between $\mathbb{Z}_n$, $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n^+$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

What is the difference between $\mathbb{Z}_n$, $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n^+$? As far as I know, + is a group with generators that generates the entire set $0 \geq x < n $ by addition (and the multiplication is with the * group). But I don't get what $Z_n$ is.

Comment: Whenever a text uses $\mathbb Z_n$, the associated operation is often implied. You just have to look at the context in which it is used. As far as I know, though, $\mathbb Z_n$ (as a group) is standard shorthand for $(\mathbb Z_n, +)$, while $\mathbb Z_n^*$ usually has some identifying notation, like $\mathbb Z_n^\times$ or $O(n)$.

Comment: Maybe $\mathbb Z_n$ is a set, and $\mathbb Z_n^*$ and $\mathbb Z_n^+$ are groups with operations of multiplication and addition, respectively

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: it could also be the ring, the multiplicative group of units, and the additive group.

Comment: Some authors use $U(n)$ for $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times$.

Comment: @Shaun: Careful: there may be a distinction between $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$. In ring theory, the first is the multiplicative semigroup/monoid of nonzero elements, while the latter is the group of units.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Thank you for the heads up :)

Answer (score 1):

Ugh... Well, for starters, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is not terribly good notation (I know a lot of books use it; but my abstract algebra course was taught by a number theorist who hates the notation because it clashes with the $p$-adic numbers, and my advisor is a ring theorist who hates it because it clashes with the *ring theoretic* notation of considering it as **ring** of integers modulo $n$).

The set $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the quotient of the group/ring $\mathbb{Z}$ modulo the subgroup/ideal $n\mathbb{Z}$. It is the group (or ring) of “integers modulo $n$.” You can view it either as the set $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ (or some other set of coset representatives), with multiplication and addition done “modulo $n$” (so $a+b$ is the usual sum $a+b$ if $a+b\lt n$, but it equals $a+b-n$ if $a+b\geq n$; and $ab$ is the remainder when you divide the usual product of $a$ and $b$ by $n$). Or you can view it as a set of congruence classes, $0+n\mathbb{Z},1+n\mathbb{Z},\ldots,(n-1)+n\mathbb{Z}$.

So...

- $\mathbb{Z}_n$ will mean either the *ring* of integers modulo $n$, or the additive group of integers modulo $n$ (which is a cyclic group of order $n$, in additive notation). Which one should be clear from context.
- $\mathbb{Z}^*_n$ is notation borrowed from ring theory. It means the *multiplicative* group of units modulo $n$. This is the group of all integers modulo $n$ that are relatively prime to $n$, which form a group under multiplication. For example, $\mathbb{Z}^*_6$ contains only the classes of $1$ and $5$ (the only integers among $0,1,2,3,4,5$ that are relatively prime to $6$), while $\mathbb{Z}^*_8$ contains the classes of $1$, $3$, $5$, and $7$. When $p$ is prime, $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ contains $1,\ldots,p-1$. This is sometimes called the “(multiplicative) group of units modulo $n$”.
- $\mathbb{Z}_n^+$ means the additive group of integers modulo $n$: it’s like $\mathbb{Z}_n$, but the $+$ superscript ensures there is no possible confusion about whether you are considering the additive group or the ring structure.

Note that $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ is not always cyclic; it is cyclic if and only if $n$ is $1$, an odd prime power, twice an odd prime power, $2$, or $4$.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of $\textit{groups}$:

$$\mathbb{Z}_n = \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} =\{[0],[1],...,[n-1] \},$$ 
where 
$[x]=\{y\in \mathbb{Z} \ : \ n \ |\ (x-y)\},$
is a $\textit{set}$ of equivalence classes;

$$\mathbb{Z}_n^{+} = (\mathbb{Z}_n,+,[0]),$$ where $[x]+[y] = [x+y],$ is a $\textit{cyclic group}$, generated by $[1]$ for example;

$$\mathbb{Z}_n^{*} = (\{[x] \in \mathbb{Z}_n\ :\ \gcd(x,n)=1 \},*,[1]),$$ where $[x]*[y] = [xy],$ is a $\textit{group}$, not cyclic in general.